# CSS class order

Tags: css, html, tags, styles

i have a main "div" with multiple divs and "a" tags and i wanted to set a "template like" css to make them all look the same, but some of the A tags need to be different so i thought about making it like this:

```
<div class="main">
   <a href="#" class="exception">CLick A</a>
   <br/>
   <a href="#">CLick B</a>
   <br/>
   <a href="#">CLick C</a>
   ....
</div>​
```

and on the css:

```
.main a{
  /* Links Scheme */
}

.exception{
 /* particular link css */
}​
```

But the browser gives preference to my "template" instead of the particular class. shouldn't the class be the most important or am i missing something?

[image: ChromeDevTools]

[FIDDLE Link](http://jsfiddle.net/joaolvcm/DFNyW/)

PS: without the use of "!important" tag please

Comment: can you also show by what it gets overwritten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue of specificity. Since `.main a` includes a class and a tag name, it is more specific, and thus gets higher precedence than just a class name.

So, to solve it, use `.main .exception` for your exception.

Answer (score 1):

.main a is more specific then .exception.  I think what you are going for is:

```
.main a{
  /* Links Scheme */
}

.main a.exception{
 /* particular link css */
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

In css, orders are also determined by how specific the selector is, so try changing `.exception` to `.main a.exception`.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/DFNyW/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:not()` pseudo-class, The `:not()` CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a list of selectors. Since it prevents specific items from being selected, it is known as the negation pseudo-class. so you can fix code like this:

```css
.main a:not(.exception){
color: #3b5998;
outline-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
}

.exception{
color: #0498ba;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
margin: 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <a href="#" class="exception">CLickA</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="#">CLickB</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="#">CLickC</a>
</div>
```